# Get rowsum for specific factor of each ID set using only certain columns in the calculation

Tags: r, dataframe

SOLVED - 
I combined the code xraynaud suggested with a rowsum to get the correct vector of sums. Now I just need to add in some code before that to make sure there are no providers missing an 'M' category.

Here is the line of code to get the rowsums:

```
rowSums(aggregate(df[df$Category=='M',24:26],by=list(df[df$Category=='M',]$Provider),sum)[,-1])
```

I have a data frame with several months of counts for about 800 providers for each of 4 different categories - the categories are 1,2,3 and 'M'.
Thus each provider has monthly counts for 1-4 different categories (not all providers have all 4 categories). These are the first two columns of the dataframe.
What I want to do is get the sum, for each provider, of the final 3 months (the last 3 columns of the df) and the 3 months previous to that (the penultimate 3 columns), of the "M" categories.
Thus I would want 2 variables (obviously would be running 2 different lines of code for these), QuarterMSUM and LQuarterMSUM. When a provider doesn't have an "M" category, I would like it to assume the sum is 0 for that provider so that every provider is in the final variable.
How can I do this?

EDIT - moving comments into original post:

the best I've come up with so far is to use aggregate and sum in the vein of

```
aggregate(df[,24:26],by=list(df$Provider),sum)
```

but, unfortunately i can't add another level of filtering to this to get only the "M" category (24:26 are the last 3 columns, with the last 3 months of counts).I can get the "M" counts for one month with

```
list(df$092014[df$PRoA=='M'])
```

but, the one month of data isnt particularly useful and it skips providers with no 'M' category. Finally, I tried rowSums (which I successfully used to get total sums for the last 3 months -

```
rowSums(aggregate(df[,24:26],by=list(df$Provider),sum)[,-1])
```

- but couldn't add enough levels of filtering to get only the 'M' sums.

Here is the structure of the data:

```
Provider|Category|102012Count|112012Count|...|092014Count

10001|1|19|33|...|29

10001|2|103|109|...|66

10001|3|59|44|...|24

10001|M|166|174|...|233

10007|2|0|0|...|21

10007|3|0|0|...|45

10007|M|0|0|...|32

10009|2|47|55|...|39

10012|1|109|107|...|113
```

Comment: the best I've come up with so far is to use aggregate and sum in the vein of aggregate(df[,24:26],by=list(df$Provider),sum) but, unfortunately i can't add another level of filtering to this to get only the "M" category (24:26 are the last 3 columns, with the last 3 months of counts).

Comment: I can get the "M" counts for one month with list(df$092014[df$PRoA=='M']) but, the one month of data isnt particularly useful and it skips providers with no 'M' category. Finally, I tried rowSums (which I successfully used to get *total* sums for the last 3 months - rowSums(aggregate(df[,24:26],by=list(df$Provider),sum)[,x]) - with x being a vector of columns to exclude, but couldn't add enough levels of filtering to get only the 'M' sums.

Comment: it would be easier if you show us what your data looks like, but why don't you aggregate only for the M category ? `aggregate(df[df$Category=='M',24:26],by=list(df$Provider),sum)`

Comment: When I run this I get an error: arguments must have same length. The error shows that df[df$Category== is the part that is problematic. I will edit the original post to show the data structure.

Comment: My bad, I forgot to update the by=list() argument. Try `aggregate(df[df$Category=='M',24:26],by=list(df[df$Category=='M',]$Provider),sum)`

Comment: So this ran without any error, but the output was a dataframe with the 'M' count for the last 3 months of each provider, instead of the sum of those 3 months. It also skipped providers that were missing the 'M' category instead of putting 0 in for them. I double checked the code and it matches yours, is there something else I might need to put in there?

Comment: OK I had some sleep and realized I just need to combine one of the attempts I had made with the code you suggested! Updating the main post and marking as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting solution in a separate answer so i can mark it as solved.

I combined the code xraynaud suggested with a rowsum to get the correct vector of sums. Now I just need to add in some code before that to make sure there are no providers missing an 'M' category.

Here is the line of code to get the rowsums:

```
rowSums(aggregate(df[df$Category=='M',24:26],by=list(df[df$Category=='M',]$Provider),sum)[,-1])
```